# Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698

Tags: openafs

I'm using SSH to access my university's afs system. I like to use rmate (remote TextMate), which requires SSH tunneling, so I included this alias in my `.bashrc`.

```
alias sshr=ssh -R 52698:localhost:52698 username@corn.myschool.edu
```

It has always worked until now.

Comment: Just a tip. At any ssh problem use `-vvv` switch to debug. If is possible try running the command at the remote server using localhost as target to validate configuration. `ssh user@remote.example.com -- ssh -vvv -R 1234:localhost:1234 localhost`. Regards,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had another SSH connection open. I just needed to close that connection before I opened my SSH tunnel.

**Further Explanation:**
Once one ssh connection has been established, subsequent connections will produce a message:

> Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698

This message is harmless, as the forward can only be set up once and one forward will work for all ssh connections to the same machine. The original ssh session that opened the forward will stay open when you exit the shell until all remote editing sessions are finished.

Comment: Where did you find your info to resolve this problem?

I have freshly powered on the server and SSHed in with reverse tunneling, tried to run rmate, and it returns the error 
    connect_to localhost port 52698: failed.
As far as I know I only have one SSH connection open. I've updated iptables to allow connections on this port. Stuck on what to try next.

Comment: Noob tip that I found useful: Remember to have Textmate running on your local machine. That actually starts the server.

Comment: If you are still getting that warning, you can logout and connect to another port by doing: ssh -R <port-number>:localhost:52698 <user>@<server>.

Answer (score 67):

I had the same problem. In order to find the port that is already open, you have to issue this command on the 'corn.myschool.edu' computer:

```
sudo netstat -plant  | grep 52698
```

And then kill all of the processes that come up with this (replace xxxx with the process ids)

```
sudo kill -9 xxxx
```

(UPDATED: changed the option to be `-plant` as it is a nice mnemonic)

Comment: On mac the command seems to be "lsof -i -P | grep 52698", but still doesn't always solve the problem (just lists Textmate for me)

Comment: I suppose it would be easier to remember if you rearranged the arguments to netstat: `sudo netstat -plant | grep 52698`... and I didn't even notice your computer was called `corn` when I wrote this! :P

Comment: The following can narrow things down to just unique pids: `sudo netstat -p | grep <your-port> | awk '{print substr($7, 0, length($7)-2)}' | sort | uniq` . The `substr` usage there is to get rid of a trailing `/0` that prints when I run this.

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem reported here as well. To avoid this notification "AllowTcpForwarding" should be enabled in SSH config.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this problem, but it was while connecting to a server on which I don't have sudo priviliges, so the top response suggesting runing `sudo netstat ...` wasn't feasible for me.

I eventually figured out it was because there were still instances of rmate running, so I used `ps` to list the running processes and then `kill -9 pid` (where pid is the process ID for rmate).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that the remote system didn't have DNS properly set up, and it couldn't even resolve its own hostname.  Make sure you have a working DNS in /etc/resolv.conf at the remote system.