# Opening file with Sublime Text via SSH to VM, error

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, sublimetext2

I do my dev work on a Mac OSX machine with a Ubuntu Server Virtual Machine installed, which I manage mostly by SSHing into it from Terminal. 
I am trying to find a way to edit files on the server using Sublime Text on the Mac rather than nano or vim from Terminal. 
I have followed the instructions contained in this excellent guide, "[Using Textmate 2s rmate with Sublime Text 2](http://canadian-fury.com/2012/06/26/using-textmate-2-s-rmate-with-sublime-text-2/)".

- I've installed rsub in Sublime Text.
- I've installed rmate on my Ubuntu server.
- I've edited my ~/.ssh/config file.
- I've added port 52698 to iptables on the server.

When I SSH into my server and run

```
rmate .profile
```

I get the error

```
connect_to localhost port 52698: failed.
```

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818131/warning-remote-port-forwarding-failed-for-listen-port-52698) refers to a similar error, but it appears to be related to having more than one SSH connection open, and I don't think that is the case for me. How could I test for that, though?

I was wondering if this could be somehow related to the fact that my dev server is a Virtual Machine with a slightly arcane internet set-up - using three different adapters that connect to the host machine's ethernet and WiFi connections. Would reverse tunnelling over SSH require different tweaking with this set-up?

Or, any other suggestions for resources or references to get this set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. issue the following command to check if port is opened in VM :

   telnet localhost 52698

If not opened then you need to open it.

Comment: Thanks! I ran that, and got

Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.connect_to localhost port 52698: failed.

Connection closed by foreign host.

Then I ran netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " and got, among other things:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52698         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 ::1:52698               :::*                    LISTEN 

Does that suggest the port is open?

Comment: you need to get it fixed then since the port is not opened that is why sublime text is failing

Comment: Noob tip that I found useful: Remember to have Sublime running on your local machine. Then you can run that command and see that it connects.

Answer (score 2):

In VirtualBox > Settings > Network > Adapter 2 (the NAT adapter) > Advanced, I added a Port Forwarding rule with hostmachine:52698 to the guestmachine:52698. This appears to have resolved it.

Comment: A further comment for myself and anyone else who comes across this answer- on my setup (Mac OSX desktop running SublimeText, Ubuntu Virtual Machine with rmate installed), I get the same error "connect_to localhost port 52698: failed." if SublimeText isn't already open on the host computer. So, first line of investigation: is SublimeText open?

Comment: Yes it's open and rsub package is installed. Same error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid port-forwarding completely, you can try something I've been working on called 'xeno' (https://xeno.io).  It's very similar to rmate/rsub, except that it does not use reverse port-forwarding to enable synchronization.  Instead, it uses a mashup of Git and SSH to enable its transport and synchronization.  This gives it a number of advantages over rmate/rsub - in particular you can edit entire folder hierarchies.  It is also completely robust to connection drop-outs, so you can even work offline and have editing changes you've made locally automatically pushed to the remote once you are back online.

It's also free and open source :), and I'd really love some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I had to kill all existing SSH sessions with

```
pkill -o -u YOURUSERNAME sshd
```

after that, it worked again.