# git pull returns Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698

Tags: git, macos

Why, when I execute `git pull`, am I getting this warning (on macos)?

> Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698

**=== EDIT ===**

```
~ $ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
my-project $ git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab.com:me/backend-api.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:me/backend-api.git (push)
```

`~/.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    name = Me
    email = me@home.com
[core]
    editor = vim
[alias]
    lg = log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
[filter "lfs"]
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[pull]
    rebase = false
```

`my-project/.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitlab.com:me/backend-api.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[pull]
    rebase = false
```

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` say?

Comment: What's the output for `which git`, `git remote -v`? Also,  looks like 52698 is related to TextMate  - `git pull` can potentially try and open a text editor IIRC. Is TextMate set as your default editor for Git? Maybe the error is coming from TextMate. Try running it directly from terminal and see if you get the same error

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for your answer, I have just updated my question with requested outputs.

Comment: @Omer Thanks for your answer, I have just updated my question with requested outputs.

Comment: Check your `~/.ssh/config`, there might be a `Host *` or `Host github.com` with a `LocalForward` or `RemoteForward` which the git client will honor when accessing github with ssh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818131/warning-remote-port-forwarding-failed-for-listen-port-52698)

Comment: @EricDarchis Indeed, that was it, I removed `~/.ssh/config` and everything is now fine. For some reason, I had `RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698` inside.

Comment: @Christoph This post helps a bit but EricDarchis comment is what helped me to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `~/.ssh/config`, there might be a `Host *` or `Host github.com` with a `LocalForward` or `RemoteForward` which the git client will honor when accessing Github with ssh.

Reposting as an answer as @DevonDahon confirmed having `RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698` in there.